# Get a list of prime numbers in python 3

Tags: python

Beginner. I'm trying to return a list that includes all the prime numbers from 0 to num. Could someone please help me find what's wrong with my code? I always get an empty list. Thanks a lot! (I'm using python 3.6)

```
def task(num):
    num = int(num)
    lst = []
    if num < 3:
        return lst
    else:
        for i in range(3,num):       
            if not i & 1:
                lst = lst
            else:
                primetest = range(3, int(i ** 0.5) + 1, 2)
                for n in primetest:
                    if i % n != 0:
                        lst.append(i)

    return lst

task(5)
```

Updates:

Thank you guys for all your comments! Really helpful.

This is what my revised code looks like.

```
def task(num):
  num = int(num)
  lst = []

  if num < 2:
    return lst

  if num >= 2:
    lst.append(2)

  for i in range(3, num + 1):       
    if i % 2 == 1:
      switch = True
      for n in range(3, int(i ** 0.5) + 1, 2):
        if i % n == 0:
          switch = False  
          break        
      if switch:
        lst.append(i)

  return lst
```

Comment: What did you tried to achieve with this peace of code `int(i ** 0.5)` ?

Comment: @YaroslavSurzhikov most likely exactly what it does: take the square root of `i`. `>>>9**0.5` -> `3.0`.

Comment: @Zinki it does not makes sence here. `3**0.5 + 1` -> `2.732050807568877`.

Comment: if see a problem with the construction of the list : 
you append each number `i` every time you find a number in the primetest range that is not a divisor of `i`

Comment: @YaroslavSurzhikov `int(3**0.5) + 1` -> `3`

Comment: what do you intend to do here? `lst = lst`?

Comment: @YaroslavSurzhikov still not seeing what you think is wrong with that. Iterating to the square root of a value and checking those values for clean division is a pretty standard prime check. `3**0.5+1 = 2.73...` is correct, what do you think is problematic about it?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I think he might not know about the `continue` statement. The `lst = lst` part is useless here

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga he probably meant that as a "do nothing" statement. Of course there are better ways (`continue`, `pass` or best of all: just negating the condition and dropping the do-nothing case entirely)

Comment: Your main problem is that your inner loop is wrong (reversed logics) and you never enter it for function inputs smaller than 10

Comment: Don't forget that 2 is also a prime number: `if num >= 2: lst.append(2)`

Answer (score 2):

The main problem lies with your inner for loop :

With your code you will append the list with `i` each time you find a number in the `primetest`range that is not a divisor of `i`.

You might want to use a boolean here to store the fact that you found a divisor of `i`, then only append it to the list if you didn't.

To answer your question, your list is empty because the `primetest`range is always empty in your example :

```
int(3**0.5) + 1 = 3  and   int(5**0.5) + 1 = 3
range(3,3,2) = []
```

The array is empty because the range function will not include the upper limit, and since the inner loop is not doing what it should be expected  to do in your code, the result will be an empty list until the parameter of the task function is superior or equal to 9

Answer (score 1):

Your code gets it wrong on several counts, tell me if you understand why the following works?

```
def task(num):
    num = int(num)
    lst = [2]
    if num < 3:
        return lst

    for i in range(3, num + 1):       
        if i % 2 == 1:
            for n in range(3, int(i ** 0.5) + 1, 2):
                if i % n == 0:
                    break
            else:
                lst.append(i)

    return lst
```

(note: the *for else* clause is **quite natural** here, *for else* clauses are used when you search for something in a loop, you break when you find that something, if not break is encountered and the regular stopIteration is used to exit the loop the else part is performed, I say it is natural here since in pseudo code you would say something like **"if my number can be divided by another number less than its square it is not prime, otherwise add it to the list of primes"** see http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/for_-_else.html for more detauls)

Its by no means a fast way to do it but I tried to stay as close to the spirit of your attempt while improving the aesthetics of the code

Comment: This also show cases the (in my opinion) very useful but under used "for else" python construct

Comment: Considering OP is likely a python beginner, you might want to drop a few words on *how* the `for else` construct operates, as it is not immediately obvious to beginners; The `else` clause is entered after the loop completes, but *ONLY* if the loop completed "naturally", i.e. without encountering a `break`.

Comment: @Zinki added an explanation and why its natural here in my opinion

Comment: `for i in range(3, num + 1, 2): for n in lst:` would be more efficient, a bit more distant from the original code, but probably worth mentioning

Comment: @VeltzerDoron Thank you so much for your comments and help. One quick question though, your code returns a list of [3,5,7,9,15] when I tested it with task(20) and 9, 15 are clearly not prime numbers, 17 and 19 are missing as well. Would you mind fixing your codes so I can learn where went wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Break the loop when the remainder is zero, i.e. `if i % n == 0:`. And the 2 is missing!

Comment: woops, fixed it, also changed ...&1 to ...% 2 == 1

Answer (score 0):

you can find prime numbers and the most dividable one in a dateset.`

```
a=[ int(x) for x in input("Enter 10 values: ").split() ]
c=[]
prime=[]
b=max(a)
for num in range(1,b+1):
    for i in range(2,num):
        if (num%i)==0:
            break
        else:
            prime.append(num)
for i in a:
    for j in prime:
        if i%j==0: 
        c.append(i)
from collections import Counter
e=Counter(c)
f=e.most_common(1)
f
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
def prim(z):
    lst = []
    for i in range(2, z+1):
        for j in range(2,i):
            if i % j == 0:
                break
        else:
            lst = lst + [i]
    return lst
```

print(prim(20))

result:

[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19]